# updated my theme on wordpress and lost custom mark ups

Tags: wordpress

I'm really pissed off with myself right now.

There's this theme on wordpress, Reddle, which I used as template to create a blog.
I edited the header.php, footer.php, CSS etc.

Then I saw on wordpress interface there was a new update for Reddle and I automatically did it. Boom, lost all of my custom and the theme practically reseted.

Luckily I was with style.css opened, so I could save it. But my mark up is all gone. So this CSS became useless.

Is there a way I can get it back?

I was trying to search on my firefox/chrome history to find the "old" version of the blog, but I can't find. Is there a way I can find it in my computer? Like in a temporary internet files or something.

Or revive this old page using firefox history?

I know that in the place I work, the browsers save history, so is there a way to open a "saved page" instead of reloading?

Comment: Your browser may or may not have a cached copy of the page. However, revisiting it, could have replaced any formerly cached copy you had of the old version of your site. Browser history alone won't do much good in this case. In the future, use child themes to avoid getting your changes overwritten: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: thanks, will do it next time!

Answer (score 0):

The best of approach in wordpress to add your custom markup or theme, is to make it child of any of the theme. And now if you update your existing theme then there will be no effect on your child theme only parent theme will be updated and you will be using that as parent so practically there will be no effect on it.

Comment: that's clever, but I didn't do that. actually, I got the idea, but not how to do it. how do I child a theme to another? I mean, two themes enabled at the same time?

Comment: @Rafael, see my comment below your question. I've provided a link to information on child themes.